# How to display today's date using JavaScript arrays & getDate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have been unable to display a date in the following format:

"Today is **Friday**, the **29th** day of **June** in the year **2019**."

I am using JavaScript within an HTML5 document. I've provided my code and appreciate any assistance. I do not want to use any 3rd party library for this other than what can be done with base level JavaScript.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--

  var monthName = new Array();
  monthName[0] = "January";
  monthName[1] = "February";
  monthName[2] = "March";
  monthName[3] = "April";
  monthName[4] = "May";
  monthName[5] = "June";
  monthName[6] = "July";
  monthName[7] = "August";
  monthName[8] = "September";
  monthName[9] = "October";
  monthName[10] = "November";
  monthName[11] = "December";

  var myYear = today.getFullYear();
  var myDate = today.getDate();

  var dayExt = "th";

  if ((myDate == 1) || (myDate == 21) || (myDate == 31)) dayExt = "st";
  if ((myDate == 2) || (myDate == 22)) dayExt = "nd";
  if ((myDate == 3) || (myDate == 23)) dayExt = "rd";

  var extDate = myDate + dayExt;

  document.write(extDate + "Today is the day of ");
  document.write(monthName[today.getMonth()] + " in the year ");
  document.write(myYear + ".");

  // -->
</script>
```

**Current result:** Nothing

**Expected result:** Today is Sunday, the 31st day of March in the year 2019.

Comment: Cause `<!--` is invalid JS?

Comment: And `today` is not defined. You might want to define it

Comment: Doesn't appear that `today` is defined anythwere either. Open browser dev tools console (F12) and check for errors. Always note errors thrown in questions

Comment: Remove `<!--` and add `var today = new Date()` near the `monthName` declaration

Comment: https://jsbin.com/rewatetoko/edit?output

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. Using a combination of your responses, and the answer I've got this script working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of going about it. The task itself is fairly straight forward - Pay attention to

1. the way arrays may be created and initialized
2. ways of checking for multiple conditions
3. way of creating a string using the templating notation - dollar-sign, curly left brace, expression, curly right brace - `${expression_goes_here}`
4. method of putting content on the page without destroying anything already present. `document.write` still gives many of us nightmares!
5. method of waiting until whole page has loaded and is available to the JS before you try to run any code that searches for or modifies content expected to be present.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
 var monthNames = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
 var dayNames = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
 var today = new Date();
 
 var dayName = dayNames[today.getDay()];
 var monthName = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
 var dayOfMonth = today.getDate();
 
 var ext = dayOfMonth % 10;  // extract last (least significant) digit
 switch (ext)
 {
  case 1:  ext = "st"; break;
  case 2:  ext = "nd"; break;
  case 3:  ext = "rd"; break;
  default: ext = "th"; break;
 }
 
 var text = `Today is ${dayName}, the ${today.getDate()}${ext} day of ${monthName} in the year ${today.getFullYear()}`;
 var textElem = document.createTextNode(text);
 document.body.appendChild(textElem);
}, false );
```

1. You can create an array with all the data already in it. You do not need to create an empty array before laboriously inserting each of the elements one at a time.
2. You should investigate the `switch` statement.
3. Use of template notation can makes things cleaner, since you can avoid closing a string, adding some value to it before adding a new string onto the end - you simply demarcate variables etc, with `${}`
4. `document.write` always used to (and I can't be bothered to check!) be a bit rough, since the first use in a page would nuke and remove any content already sent to the browser (scripts, styles, etc, etc) A better solution is to create an HTML element of some description, set the content of that element before adding that element to the page. I've used a text-node, which is vaguely the equivalent to "no-element" - the text wont be surrounded by angled brackets and an html tag.
5. You might notice the whole code is wrapped in brackets. I've told the browser that when an event is fired that signals all of the html elements have been read, parsed and are available for interaction, I'd like to be notified.

Here's the form:

`window.addEventListener('load', callThisFuncWhenLoadEventReceived, false);`

I could specify the name of a function to be called in response to this event, OR I could do as I've done here and use a function without a name (an anonymous function)

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down for me I got it working!